# How to find the transitional matrix

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Find the transitional matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$ and from $B_2$ to $B_1$

[image]

I stumbled upon this problem. We need to find a transitional matrix. I would usually find a matrix from $B_1$ to  standard basis and then from standard basis to $B_2$. To get to standard basis, I would just rewrite the columns from $B_1$ to then take the inverse matrix, so to get $(P_{B_2S})^{-1} = P_{SB_2}$ and then I would do $P_{SB_2}P_{B_1S}$ and get to the $B_2$ basis. I cannot do that here, since I cannot find an inverse of a matrix that is $2\times 4$.

How to do it?

Comment: A way to adapt what you said you know how to do is to enlarge both bases of these 2 dimensional spaces into bases of $\mathbb{R}^4$, then follow the procedure you said. Assuming the spans here are actually the same (which is not immediately obvious), you will find that the coefficients of these two vectors in $\mathcal{B}_2$ only depend on the corresponding coefficients for $\mathcal{B}_1$ and so the transformation you're looking for is actually 2x2 as it should be.

Comment: That being said, a shorter way to do this particular problem would be to just start writing down each vector in terms of the vectors in the other basis one at a time. For an example of the latter, if $(1,0,-1,1)^T=c_1(2,-1,-1,1)^T+c_2(1,1,-2,2)^T$ then $2c_1+c_2=1,-c_1+c_2=0$ so $c_1=c_2=1/3$. Then you check that this actually works out in the other two components (which, generically, it wouldn't, but it does if you pick the vectors just right).

Comment: @Ian So, if I would want to add 2 vectors into the basis to do the procedure, that I want to do, I would add 2 vectors that are dependend on the 2 vectors that are in the basis before right ?

Comment: They should be independent of the vectors you started with, and also independent of each other, so that the resulting 4 vectors are linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @Ian so actually the new vector must not be the combination of the first two combined, or it is enough that it is independend from the others individually

Comment: The third vector can't be a combination of the first two, and the fourth vector can't be a combination of the first three.